# How can I populate meta tags before the page is completely loaded in Nuxt?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt3 application where a blog article is loaded from Firestore using an ID that is passed as a path variable. To make my site more SEO friendly, I want to populate Nuxt title and meta tags (<Title> and <Meta>) with information regarding the article such as the title and images. However, it seems that by the time that the article data was retrieved from Firestore, the page has loaded, leaving the meta tags temporarily empty. Although it is temporary, since the request is deemed to be completed, the meta tags are considered to be empty when tested on Postman. SSR is set to true. I prefer to use the Options API, if possible.

Is there a solution that would allow for the meta tags to be populated with the data fetched from Firestore before the page has loaded?

I tried playing with SSR settings and moving the code in `beforeMount()` to `created()` and `mounted()` , but no luck. I am new to Nuxt, and it would be fabulous if you could help me out.

/pages/app/[id].vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "AppPage",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      catchphrase: "",
      images: [],
      description: "",
      owner: "",
      url: "",
      isOwner: false,
    };
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const id = this.$route.params.id;
    const docRef = await doc(this.$db, "apps", id);
    getDoc(docRef).then(async (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        const data = doc.data();
        this.title = data.title;
        this.catchphrase = data.catchphrase;
        this.images = data.images;
        this.description = data.description;
        this.owner = await (await getDoc(data.owner)).data();
        this.url = data.url;

        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            if (user.uid === this.owner.id) {
              this.isOwner = true;
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <Head>
    <Title>{{ title }}</Title>
    <Meta name="description" :content="catchphrase"/>
    <Meta property="og:title" :content="title"/>
    <Meta property="og:description" :content="catchphrase"/>
    <Meta property="og:image" :content="images[0]"/>
    <Meta property="og:url" :content="url"/>
    <Meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <Meta property="og:site_name" content="Circle4Devs"/>
    <Meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
    <Meta name="twitter:site" content="@Circle4Devs"/>
    <Meta name="twitter:title" :content="title"/>
    <Meta name="twitter:description" :content="catchphrase"/>
    <Meta name="twitter:image" :content="images[0]"/>
  </Head>

  <div id="article">
      ...
  </div>
```

Here is a response given by postman. The meta tags are empty

[image]

Here is a response given by the browser a few moment after the page has loaded. The meta tags here are populated.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Nuxt 3 Documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#usehead) and tried the `useHead()` function to set meta info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useHead` Composable

```
useHead({
  title: "My page with ads",
  // or, instead:
  // titleTemplate: (title) => `My App - ${title}`,
  viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1",
  charset: "utf-8",
  meta: [{ name: "description", content: "My amazing site." }]
})
```

You can use the `useSeoMeta` Composable too:

```
useSeoMeta({
  description: 'My about page',
  ogDescription: 'Still about my about page',
  ogTitle: 'About',
  ogImage: '<>',
  twitterCard: 'summary_large_image',
})
```

Or even, for performance reasons, `useServerSeoMeta`:

```
useServerSeoMeta({
  robots: 'index, follow'
})
```

You should place them inside your `<script>` tag and don't need to import anything.

Sources:

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-seo-meta

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-server-seo-meta